# Loading a file into main memory

Tags: java, file, optimization, nlp, tokenize

I have this text file that contains a list of words and a bunch of scores associated with each of them. I want to read the words off the file and the words and use them in my project. The code is in Java and the file itself is around 13MB. When I try to read file it takes around 15 minutes to complete, sometime even more. Any ideas on how I should optimize or approach this problem from scratch.

The operations being performed on file are - 
1. Read each line (Around 50 chars on the average case)
2. Split into tokens using a single whitespace (Around 10 tokens in the average case)
3. Store the generated tokens in an array (Nothing more at this stage)

EDIT: Sorry for not posting my code before, it just slipped my mind. http://pastie.org/3646388
There is an line there where I loop to 10000 values which was to see if I got any output as opposed to looping till EOF.

Comment: Could you share your code as well? There may be some optimizations possible.

Comment: If it's taking that long either you are running this on a commodore 64 or there's something wrong with your code ... which we can't see.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above, more code is helpful, but 15 minutes to read a 13MB file is very slow even on nowadays PCs. I don't think the file operation is the bottleneck here. My suggestions: 1. if the step 2, which split tokens is using more CPU than expected? if so, optimize the code there; 2, if the step 3 needs a lot of memory allocation operation, allocate a big enough array at first(or ArrayList?), and tune the JVM to have bigger startup heap.

Comment: As a start, I'd suggest that you profile your code and determine where it is spending its time. That's the best way of directing your efforts in the right direction.

Comment: On a fast PC you should be able to read with BufferedReader a file at a rate of 90 MB/s. It should take about 0.3 to 0.6 seconds.

Comment: @BrianRoach I am not sure what to say here. Either my code is abysmally written or I have missed somethign really big from my Java programming class.

Comment: @JerryTian I've never had the opportunity to use a profiler before, so will do that.

Comment: @All Please have a look at my code. Does this question also need a downvote? Thank you for the support so for! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to post a sample of your code, otherwise we're just speculating. However, if you're using `java.io` classes (InputStream or Reader) then make sure that you're wrapping your InputStream or Reader with a BufferedInputStream or BufferedReader.

Since you're reading text, the code to construct your reader might look something like:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/path/to/file")));
```

From the [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/BufferedReader.html) JavaDoc:

> In general, each read request made of a Reader causes a corresponding
>   read request to be made of the underlying character or byte stream. It
>   is therefore advisable to wrap a BufferedReader around any Reader
>   whose read() operations may be costly, such as FileReaders and
>   InputStreamReaders.

You should also consider profiling your code. If you don't have a profiler handy, try [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html). It's packaged with the JDK.

Comment: It works even better if you also wrap the `FileInputStream` with a `BufferedInputStream`. It seems odd that double buffering would help, but (at least on many systems) it does.

Comment: FileInputStream doesn't have any buffering.

Comment: I think @TedHopp meant warping it using an inputstream.

Comment: @viki.omega9 - No, I meant "wrapping": `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("path"))))`.

Comment: @Tedd Hopp Interesting... I would not have guessed that using both a BufferedReader and BufferedInputStream would make any difference. How much of a speedup have you seen doing this? Do you know what accounts for the performance improvement?